# Netbeans IDE - Automatic Suggestion while typing

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

hi i am using netbeans 7 IDE for java programming , and i am acutally a C# programmer and in visual studio whenever i type anything it displays a dropdown menu with suggestions , i want that to be enabled on netbeans IDE without having to press CTRL + Space to show the dropdown menu

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, Netbeans gives suggestion only when you put a period (i.e. for class and object fields and methods).

However, you can customize auto-completion by going to

Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion

Choose whatever configuration works best for you.

Hope this help!

Comment: Didn`t work i tried typing Sys to show me System but didn`t work

Comment: Okay it works now , i choose Language : Java and i checked the second Auto popup on typing any java identifier part

Answer (score 1):

Do this

1. Goto Tools
2. Select options
3. then click on code completion
4. Go to All Languages > Java > select all

- select "Auto popup on typing any Java identifier Part"
- select "SubWord completion"
- select "Guess Filled method arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the Code Assistance (e.g., Tools → Options → C/C++ → Code Assistance), in case of C/C++, you added your compiler's include directories.

You can find the compiler you are using in Project Properties → Build → X Compiler

Answer (score 0):

a common response to your answer suggesting the automatic code completion in netbeans IDE is as follows,

1. Goto Tools
2. Select options
3. then click on code completion
4. Select neccessary checkboxes you want and then click on apply then click ok.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what was already mentioned, you can also do the following to always have suggestions:
Tools > Options > Editor > In Languages select Java > Auto Popup triggers for Java paste the following: .@(#&$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ